# Calculation of tithi

Tags: astrology

What is solar Longitude and  Lunar Longitude while calculating tithi[(Lunar Longitude-solar Longitude)/12]. I could not get their meaning and values anywhere. How are they connected to their Azimuth angle and altitude angle? Because I only find these values.

Comment: You will find all the answers regarding the above in a book by Jean Meeus called "Astronomical Algorithms".